# Can I get (the new) bash on Windows 10 to load .profile

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the new subsystem for Linux on Windows 10 (which comes with the Windows anniversary update), and started playing around with it.

What I noticed is that starting the shell (ubuntu bash) does not load .profile or .bash_profile, even though the .profile file exists. Is there a fix?

(And can someone with a lot of reputation make the windows-bash tag?)

Comment: That tag exists already: [tag:ubuntu-on-windows].

Comment: FYI: Feel free to move this to Super User if you guys prefer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, this release of Ubuntu-on-windows loads the file named `.bashrc`.

You can either put the script or add the below line to `.bashrc` (and create `.bashrc` if it is non-existent):

```
. ~/.profile
```

Note: If `.bashrc` is sourced from `.profile`, you may want to comment it out to prevent bash endlessly looping.

Comment: Thanks luk3yx; but I mentioned specifically that this fails with Ubuntu-on-windows.

Comment: Ah, it actually works. .bashrc is included/run, even though the system appears to be setup the other way around; as the following lines are included in the default ~/.profile

if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, you probably want to remove/comment the lines that source .bashrc from your .profile otherwise you will wind up in a loop when .profile is sourced in .bashrc